# get full string before first second third etc. split

Tags: vb.net, split

I have a file location and I need to check if it exists.

The way I wan't to do it is like this:

```
        Dim route As String = ("C:\testing1\testing2\testing3\testing4\testing5\TEXTBESTAND.txt")
        If System.IO.File.Exists(route) Then
            MsgBox("BESTAAT HET WERKT!")
        Else
            Dim subroute() As String = route.Split("\"c)
            Dim counting As Integer = route.Split("\"c).Length - 1
            For count2 As Integer = 0 To counting - 1

                Dim firstbackslash As Integer = route.IndexOf("\")
                Dim backslash As Integer = route.IndexOf("\", firstbackslash + 1)
                Dim firstPart As String = route.Substring(0, backslash)
                MsgBox(firstPart)
           
            Next
```

What I try  to accomplisch is that I fist check if folder "C:" exists then "C:\testing1" then "C:\testing1\testing2" etc.

But I cant find something like this on the internet nor with some messing around...

Comment: Take a look at `System.IO.Path`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an algorithm that that will give you all the paths starting from the root and building up to the final path including the filename.  You can use this to check for each folder and create them as you go if they don't exist:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim route As String = ("C:\testing1\testing2\testing3\testing4\testing5\TEXTBESTAND.txt")

    Dim fi As New System.IO.FileInfo(route)
    If Not fi.Exists Then
        Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileName(route)

        Dim di As DirectoryInfo = fi.Directory
        Dim pathStack As New Stack(Of String)()
        pathStack.Push(di.Name)
        While Not IsNothing(di.Parent)
            di = di.Parent
            pathStack.Push(di.Name)
        End While

        Dim curPath As String = ""
        While pathStack.Count > 0
            curPath = Path.Combine(curPath, pathStack.Pop)
            ' ... do something with "curPath" in here ...
            ' ... like check for existence and create it ...
            Console.WriteLine(curPath)
        End While

        curPath = Path.Combine(curPath, fileName)
        ' ... do something with "curPath" in here ...
        ' ... this is the full path including the file on the end ...
        Console.WriteLine(curPath)
    End If

    Console.Write("Press Enter to quit...")
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Output:

```
C:\
C:\testing1
C:\testing1\testing2
C:\testing1\testing2\testing3
C:\testing1\testing2\testing3\testing4
C:\testing1\testing2\testing3\testing4\testing5
C:\testing1\testing2\testing3\testing4\testing5\TEXTBESTAND.txt
Press Enter to quit...
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use string mnaipulation to work with file or folder paths. use the `Path` class.

One option:

```vb
Private Function GetExistingSubPath(fullPath As String) As String
    If Directory.Exists(fullPath) OrElse File.Exists(fullPath) Then
        Return fullPath
    End If

    Dim subPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath)

    If subPath Is Nothing Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    Return GetExistingSubPath(subPath)
End Function
```

Sample usage:

```vb
Dim fullPath = "C:\testing1\testing2\testing3\testing4\testing5\TEXTBESTAND.txt"
Dim existingSubPath = GetExistingSubPath(fullPath)

Console.WriteLine(existingSubPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

> What I try to accomplisch is that I fist check if folder "C:" exists then "C:\testing1" then "C:\testing1\testing2" etc.

Noooooooooooo!

That's not how to do it at all!  The file system is volatile: things can change between each of those checks. Moreover, file existence is only one of many things that can stop file access.

It's much better practice to try to access the file in question, and then handle the exception if it fails. Remember, because of the prior paragraph you have to be able to handle exceptions here anyway. `.Exists()` doesn't save you from writing that code. And each check is another round of **disk access**, which is about the slowest thing it's possible to do in a computer... even slower than unrolling the stack for an exception, which is the usual objection to this idea.

Comment: I know it is not the best way to do it. But I only need to Check if there there ( and that is 99,999% of the time) and if there not. I need to put a text file at that exact location with something in it.

Comment: Then just put the file there, and handle the exception if it fails. You have to be able to do that anyway.

Comment: I am not that good yet, I only code a view months. I learned this by doing stuff and failing a lot ;). If you know some good coding book for VB.Net I would like to know.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, know I can check if multiple text files are at the locations I need, if there not I place the Textfiles at the location I need them. Then I can add something in it. (I need to put a Location of something else in it.)

```
        Dim een As String = "C:\testing1\testing2\testing7\testing1\testing1\text.txt"
        Dim twee As String = "C:\testing1\testing2\testing7\testing2\testing1\text.txt"
        Dim drie As String = "C:\testing1\testing2\testing7\testing3\testing1\text.txt"
        Dim vier As String = "C:\testing1\testing2\testing7\testing4\testing1\text.txt"

        Dim Files As String() = {een, twee, drie, vier}

        For Each route As String In Files
            If System.IO.File.Exists(route) Then
                MsgBox("BESTAAT HET WERKT!")
            Else
                Dim subroute() As String = route.Split("\"c)
                Dim counting As Integer = route.Split("\"c).Length - 1
                Dim tel As Integer = route.Substring(route.LastIndexOf("\") + 1).Count
                Dim bestandnaam As String = route.Substring(route.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)
                For count2 As Integer = 0 To route.Length - tel - 1

                    Dim firstbackslash As Integer = route.IndexOf("\", count2)
                    Dim backslash As Integer = route.IndexOf("\", count2)
                    Dim Mapnaam As String = route.Substring(0, backslash)
                    count2 = firstbackslash

                    If System.IO.Directory.Exists(Mapnaam) Then
                    Else
                        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Mapnaam)
                    End If
                Next
                If System.IO.File.Exists(route) Then
                Else
                    Dim objStreamWriter As System.IO.StreamWriter
                    objStreamWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter(route)
                    Dim label As String
                    Select Case route
                        Case een
                            label = "een"
                        Case twee
                            label = "twee"
                        Case drie
                            label = "drie"
                        Case vier
                            label = "vier"
                    End Select
                    Dim value As String = InputBox("Route invullen naar " & label)

                    'Dim objStreamWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(route)

                    objStreamWriter.Write(value)
                    objStreamWriter.Close()
                    'Using sw As System.IO.StreamWriter = System.IO.File.AppendText(route)
                    '    sw.WriteLine(value)
                    'End Using
                End If

            End If

        Next route
```